# You start with 19 cookies. 1 cookie is eaten away every day. Everyday you are day * 1/4 tolerance of hunger. How many days until starve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

You start with 19 cookies. 1 cookie is eaten every day. You also earn `1/4 * day` of tolerance to hunger every day. When `cookie + tolerance = 0` you die. Your score is how many days you lasted. How much score will you earn with 19 cookies? How do you calculate how many days you have left until stravation at any day only only knowing your cookie count and tolerance?

Tolerance example: day 19 you will have `day / 4` tolerance which is 4.75 hunger tolerance. Even though you don't have any cookies left, you will not starve because of the tolerance. You will continue to grow tolerance after you reached 0 cookies.

Python code:

```
cookie = 19
day = 0
result = 0

while True:
    cookie = cookie - 1
    tolerance = day / 4
    if (cookie + tolerance <= 0):
        result = day / 1
        break
    print("Cookie: " + repr(cookie))
    print("Tolerance : " + repr(tolerance ))
    print("Total: " + repr(cookie + tolerance ))
    print((cookie + tolerance)*4/3.0) // Answer formula that calculates how many days you have left until no starve, but how is this derived?
    day = day + 1

print()
print("Result: " + repr(result))
```

Comment: For those who saw the previous cookie question, I made a terrible mistake. This is actually what I meant.

Comment: You could have edited your previous question instead of deleting it and creating a new one.

Comment: Is cookie is eaten away every day, including the days you haven't one left? So can you have e.g. -5 cookies?

Comment: Yes. But form a logic standpoints basically you're starving.

Comment: @wythagoras Someone answered the mistaken question. It was a fine question on it's own so I left it as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 cookie is eating away every day, so you lose one score point. You earn $\frac{1}{4}$th score point by tolerance. So you lose a net of $\frac{3}{4}$ score points a day.

You start with 19 score points. Since $\frac{19}{\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)}=25 \frac{1}{3}$, we look to the situation at the 26th day. Before tolerance and cookie change, we have 0.25 score left. Therefore we reach -0.50 after the change, meaning we will die at the 26th day.

In general, if you have $a$ score points left, you will die on the $\lceil\frac{4a}{3} \rceil$th day from then. (i.e. the day on which you have $a$ score points, is day 1.)

$\lceil n \rceil$ is the ceil function, meaning the smallest integer larger than or equal to $n$.